# Magento | How to sort a product collection by category ids?

Tags: magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't sort product collection by category id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618844/i-cant-sort-product-collection-by-category-id)

I have a few categories: guys, ladies, men, women and offers.

Every product is assigned to guys, ladies, men OR women categories.

And some products are assigned to "offers" category.

I need to retrieve every "offers" products but sort by the others categories, I mean:

OFFERS
 -> guys products
 -> ladies products
 -> men products
 -> women products

Right now I am getting the products to display by the category "offers", but this products cames ordered by name attribute and I need those products sorted by category before name.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSort('category', 'ASC');
```

This will sort the product by category, rather than by name. The addAttributeToSort method will take any of the models existing attributes as a parameter.

Comment: Care to explain why it was downvoted?