# How to sort product collection by category_id in descending order in Magento

Tags: magento, sorting, categories

I want to **sort product collection by category_id in descending order**. But it is not working. This is the code that I am using.

```
$_productCollection = $product->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) // Only catalog, search visiblity
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
                        ->addAttributeToSort('category_id', 'DESC')
                        ->setCurPage(1)
                        ->setPageSize(12);
```

The problem is `addAttributeToSort('category_id', 'DESC')`  not working for me.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618844/i-cant-sort-product-collection-by-category-id

Comment: you cannot use category_id as an attribute.